# How to iterate over an array of variables and get the field name for each?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to iterate over an array of variables and then push / console.log the variable name of each.

This code is not working as I thought it might.

```
let firstOne = true;
let secondOne = true;
let thirdOne = false;

let errorArray = [firstOne, secondOne, thirdOne];

errorArray.forEach((element) => {
  if (element == true) {
    console.log((Object.keys({ element })[0]));
  }
});
```

I was expecting to see firstOne, secondOne in the console.log but instead, it's just 'element'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays don't have keys. They use numeric indexes. To get the key, you'll need to use an object. To iterate the object convert it to an array of `[key, value]` pairs using `Object.entries()`. When you iterate the array of pairs, use destructuring to get the `element` and the `key`.

```js
let firstOne = true;
let secondOne = true;
let thirdOne = false;

let errorArray = Object.entries({ firstOne, secondOne, thirdOne });

errorArray.forEach(([key, element]) => {
  if (element) {
    console.log(key);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to another answer but slightly different syntax but the concept remains to convert the object into an array and iterate over it as a key/value pair.

```js
let firstOne = true;
let secondOne = true;
let thirdOne = false;

let errorObjs = {
  firstOne,
  secondOne,
  thirdOne
};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(errorObjs)) {
  if (value) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
  }
}
```